# SQL error command not properly ended

Tags: sql

i tried to create this table

```
 drop table Properties constraint cascade;
 create table Properties (
     Prop_num number(10),
     type varchar2(6) ,
     country varchar2(6) ,
     city varchar2(6) , 
     street varchar2(6) , 
     Room_num number(10) ,
     Prop_description varchar2(100) ,
     price number(10) , 
     constraint Prop_num PRIMARY KEY(Prop_num)
);
```

and this error massage show **SQL command not properly ended**
...

create table contract(

contract_num number(10) ,

type varchar2(6) ,

payment_method varchar2(6),

cust_id  char(10) ,

Prop_num number(10),

constraint contract_num PRIMARY KEY(contract_num));

The error appears on all data type 
Unknow command begining " cont....." - rest of line ignored
this error appears on all coulmn

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Does the first statement complete successfully?

Comment: I think it's Oracle and `constraint cascade` should be `cascade constraints`

Comment: i change it to cascade constraints and its worked

Comment: but the second no

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Oracle, change

```
 drop table Properties constraint cascade;
```

to:

```
 drop table Properties cascade constraints;
```

Comment: i created this table drop table contract cascade constraint ;
create table contract(
  
contract_num number(10) , 
type varchar2(6) , 
payment_method varchar2(6), 
cust_id  char(10) , 
Prop_num number(10),
constraint contract_num PRIMARY KEY(contract_num)); and this error showed table or view does not exist

Comment: drop is *not* a part of create. those are two separate commands. If you didn't have the table `contract` before, it is expected to throw that error.

Comment: Also, `constraints` instead of `constraint`

Comment: thank you so much but the same error appears all the data type of the table became as unknown command beginning :(

Comment: Please post whatever the issue along with error you're getting in the question. It may be worthwhile to look for basic Oracle tutorials.

Comment: okay , i write create table contract(
  
contract_num number(10) , 
type varchar2(6) , 
payment_method varchar2(6), 
cust_id  char(10) , 
Prop_num number(10),
constraint contract_num PRIMARY KEY(contract_num));

Comment: them all the datatype became error " nknown command beginning "

Comment: @Lama in the question please.